# switch from auth_user to CustomUser in Django 1.7

Tags: mysql, django, python-2.7, django-models

I had been using auth.User user model. Now I changed my user model to custom.CustomUser. There were various models which were made during use of auth.User. So every tables in my database of mysql has created column name user_id or has constraint of foreign key with 'auth_user'. Due to which lots of problem are occuring. Everything other than this is working fine. AUTH_USER_MODEL is pointing to my 'custom.CustomUser' table and every new user is being stored in CustomUser. Is there any way of changing the reference of existing tables from auth_user to custom_customuser. I am using Django 1.7 which does not support south (As far as I know).

Comment: south is an inbuilt module for Django in 1.7. you don't need to install south explicitly.! you can try pointing all auth.User to CustomUser in your models and create new migrations

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to update your models to point to settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, as you mentioned. Here's an example:

```
your_field = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='yourmodel_yourfield')
```

Then, you'll need to use Django's internal migrations. Andrew Godwin, who wrote South, is now a core contributor to Django, so they should be fairly familiar to anyone using South:

Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/

If you're upgrading to 1.7, it is worth making the jump to 1.8 as well. You'll need to modify your TEMPLATE settings and urls.py patterns. 1.8 is a long term Django release. Good luck!